# How to pass parts of a command as variable bash?

Tags: linux, bash

```
a="grep ssh | grep -v grep"
ps -ef | $a | awk '{print $2}'
```

How can I make the above work?  I have a section where I need to not just pass the grep term, but possible pass more than one grep term, meaning I need to pass "term1 | grep term2" as a variable.

Edit:

another.anon.coward answer below worked perfectly for me. Thank you sir!

Comment: How about `ps -ef | eval "$a" | awk '{print $2}'`? Or better option would be `pgrep` as suggested in case you are dealing only with process ids

Comment: @another.anon.coward Post the eval solution as an answer.

Comment: Please consider the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18987842/925381) suggested by [konsolebox](http://stackoverflow.com/users/445221/konsolebox) as it covers both alternative to `eval` and `eval` solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function instead:

```
a() {
    grep ssh | grep -v grep
}
ps -ef | a | awk '{print $2}'
```

The other solution is to use eval but it's unsafe unless properly sanitized, and is not recommended.

```
a="grep ssh | grep -v grep"
ps -ef | eval "$a" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the `pid` of a process, then use `pgrep`.

```
pgrep ssh
```

You can put this in a bash like the following (a.bash) :

```
#!/bin/bash
pname=$1
pgrep "$pname"
```

or if you want `ps -ef` for other purposes as you've written, following inside a script might work:

```
pname=$1
ps -ef | grep "$pname" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'  # I would personally prefer this
```

OR

```
ps -ef | eval "$pname" | awk '{print $2}'  # here $pname can be "grep ssh | grep -v grep"
```

change the permission to execute :

```
chmod a+x a.bash
./a.bash ssh
```

Comment: I am looking to do more than just the Pid, above is just a very simple example.  My commands get to be like                          ps -ef|grep "${!db}" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $13}' |awk -F '/' '{print "IP  = "$3}'   But in some cases I need to grep a single term, on others I need to pass a second.

Comment: edited my answer. I would still prefer to put `grep` or other bash command inside the script and only use variables as arguments...